# angular module files are not found after bundling

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, webpack, migration

Currently i'm trying to migrate my Angular JS project to Angular (11+).
Because it's a large project, i wanted to bootstrap AngularJS and Angular in a hybrid mode, so that i can upgrade everything gradually.

I didn't use Webpack before that. After creating the webpack bundle and trying to load the app, i got the following errors that some @angular files are not found. As an example:
**GET https://localhost/learn/templates/0/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/src/core net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**
Although the paths to those files are correct, i only recognized that they're missing their .js file extensions.
[Error stack trace in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9apyg.png)

This is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./main.ts",
output: {
    filename: "./angular/bundle/bundledProjectModule.js"
},
resolve: {
    extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
},
module: {
    rules: [
        //all files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: "ts-loader" }
    ]
}
};
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "es2019.object"]
  },  
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is my main.ts file:

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-resource';
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-aria';
import 'angular-messages';
import 'angular-sanitize';
import 'angular-route';

import './learn.main'

import './angular/generalComponents/button';
import './angular/generalComponents/cell-items';
import './angular/generalComponents/filter/search-bar';
import './angular/generalComponents/filter/date';
import './angular/generalComponents/view-fields';
import './angular/generalServices';

import './modules/project';
import './modules/project/overview/filter';
import './modules/project/overview/table';
import './modules/project/overview';

import './polyfills';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {UpgradeModule} from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    // Override Angular bootstrap so it doesn't do anything
    ngDoBootstrap() {
    }
}

// Bootstrap using the UpgradeModule
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    console.log("Bootstrapping in Hybrid mode with Angular & AngularJS");
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['learn']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Install node_modules by running the command "npm i" in your terminal in your main project folder. It will resolve the problem.